# jQuery: keep a div in page center, even if page is scrolled down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to center a div on the screen so that when the page is scrolled down/up, the div scrolls smoothly to the center of the page. I am trying [this code (please see jsfiddle),](http://jsfiddle.net/8Dupa/) but does not work. Can someone help me with it? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need jquery for that, just use css

**HTML**

```
<div id="senad">content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #senad { width: 200px; height: 200px; position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; border: 1px solid gray;}
```

Thi will keep element on center.

Comment: thanks but i cant use CSS only, because the height of the div is not always same, so if height is more, half of the div remains hidden.

Comment: I guess you are using CSS to set the height — so why not set the `position:fixed` at the same time?

Answer (score 6):

Why not just mark it `position: fixed` and keep it there regardless of where the user scrolls? Then you don't need any form of javascript trickery.

However, to answer your current problem, it seems you provide the centering once, you you never react to the scroll event of the window:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() { $('#box').center(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.  Updated with a scroll event and consideration of document.body.scrollTop

http://jsfiddle.net/8Dupa/4/

$(window).scroll(function() { $('#box').center(); });

and within center()

top += document.body.scrollTop;

Answer (score 1):

use this plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.center = function(){
this.css("position","absolute");
this.css("top","50%");
this.css("left","50%");
this.css("margin-top","-"+(this.height()/2)+"px");
this.css("margin-left","-"+(this.width()/2)+"px");
return this;}

$("#id").center();
```